# Text debris in Qt frameless transparent window

Tags: qt, go

I'm trying to create a frameless transparent window with Qt and its go-bind(https://github.com/therecipe/qt).

The problem I have faced is that the debris of the text remains in the frameless transparent window. Please look at Gif(https://i.imgur.com/47OC7ps.gif).

The characteristics of the problem I confirmed are the following.

- Problems only occur in resized windows. (But not 100%)
- Only the text initially
  displayed in the window will remain as debris.

This problem can be avoided by explicitly calling `Hide()`, `Show()` in QMainWindow itself, but performance problems occur.

I expect that there will be some consideration for resizing the application since the problem occurs only in resized window.

Are there any ideas?

---

My environment is the following:

- Qt: 5.12.0
- My app source code: https://github.com/akiyosi/goqtframelesswindow commit:8d7aa6e

Comment: Perhaps, you widget doesn't see that this region needs to be updated.Try to call `update()` (without parameters) to force your whole widget to be repainted.

Comment: Even after `update()` debris will continue to remain. Also, I confirmed that this problem occurs only in MacOS. In WIndows problem does not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

This problem is caused by the shadow of the window in MacOS.
I was able to work around this issue by setting `Qt::NoDropShadowWindowHint` to the window.

Perhaps this problem is a bug of MacOS/Qt.